# I would like to do a loop through every row of a multi-index table and only show columns that are not blank in that particular row

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to do a loop through every row of a multi-index table and only show columns that are not blank in that particular row.

The idea is to produce a list of changes for each employee that I can cross reference against the list of changes sent by HR. If the column shows nothing, nothing has changed between last month and this month so I don't need to review it. But if the difference column shows a change in pay, deductions, bonus, health insurance etc. I would like to see the output.

With help from answers to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756526/merging-two-payroll-reports-in-python-pandas-and-then-producing-columns-comparin), I have recently been generating a report in Pandas that compares the current payroll report to the previous month's and creates changes columns for all variables. It looks something like this:

| Employee Code | Surname | Salary (new) | Pension (new) | Salary (old) | Pension (old) | Salary (diff) | Pension (diff) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Jones | 3,600 | 1,500 | 3,600 | 1,200 |  | 300 |
| 31 | Smith | 4,000 | 1,900 | 3,500 | 1,900 | 500 |  |
| 39 | Brown | 3,000 | 850 | 2,600 | 1,000 | 400 | -150 |
| 42 | Haydn | 4,000 | 1,000 | 4,000 | 1,000 |  |  |

Please note that the actual report has 50-60 columns each month so the output is actually 150-180 columns, not just Salary and Pension but lots of other deductions, bonuses etc. It also doesn't actually say "Salary (new)" and so on. It is a multi index with Old, New and Difference at the top, and the columns below that are the Salary, Pension etc.

I would like to use pandas to go through this and in the example above produce something like this:

| Employee Code | Surname | Pension(diff) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Jones | 300 |

| Employee Code | Surname | Salary(diff) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | Smith | 500 |

| Employee Code | Surname | Salary(diff) | Pension(diff) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39 | Brown | 400 | -150 |

Jones had pension changes but no salary changes so it only shows the Pension (diff) column. For Smith it's the other way around. For Brown both changed so it shows both. Nothing has changed for Haydn so he doesn't appear at all.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with the commenter itprorh66

```
# only Salary is different... make a df for only salary
df_sal = df[df['Salary (diff)'].notna()]
# only Pension is different... make a df for only Pension
df_pen = df[df['Pension (diff)'].notna()]
# both are different
df_both = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
print(df_sal, '\n' , df_pen, '\n', df_both)
```

---

Update

---

loop through all columns to display the df without NaN in that specific column.

```
for column in df:
    dfn = df[df[column].notna()]
    print(dfn)
```

Comment: Thanks, Shane - super helpful. Yeah, I do get the difference now that itprorh has explained it - it's hard to know where to start with code sometimes. I will go away and try to code based on your suggestion. The only problem is there are about 60 ever-changing columns not just the two in the example, so it will require a loop. Maybe instead of 'Pension (diff)' or whatever it could be something like this?
   
"for i in range(61, 121):
    df.loc[:,i].notna()=True"

Comment: If you feel like the question is easy to answer but you don't know it yourself one option is the askcodi website.